# Could you please explain this code fragment in python

Tags: python, exception

I'm brand new to python, and need some help understanding this code fragment:

```
for c in [B, C, D]:
   try:
      raise c()
   except D:
      print "D"
    except C:
      print "C"
    except B:
      print "B"
```

Reading python docs, it seems `raise()` throws an exception, but I can't figure out why `raise()` is within the `try` block. Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
try:
    //do something
catch:
    raise()
```

Comment: Without knowing what the code is supposed to accomplish, it is 100% impossible to know which version is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raise` is how you raise exceptions in the first place. A lone `raise` in an exception handler only propagates the exception to external handlers.

Comment: ohh, gotcha. So, the code within the try block is essentially raising an exception depending on the value of `c`?

Comment: It's raising an instance of the exception class in `c`.

Comment: In Python, everything is an object - including classes themselves. The name `c` is bound to each class in turn; `c()` creates an instance of the corresponding exception class each time through the loop, which is then `raise`d.

Answer (score 2):

I presume the raise() was placed directly inside try: just for the purpose of illustration. 
And even normally you would put the code causing an exception (i.e one containing raise()) inside try, won't you?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. After thinking about it some more, I realized raising an exception would make sense inside a `try` block

Answer (score 1):

That code is kind of ridiculous in that its a bizarre way of doing things, but its pretty clear what's going on.  The list `[B, C, D]` is a list of exceptions.  Since the exception is `raise`d in a `try` block, it is immediately handled by the appropriate `except` handler (in succession, the `except B:`, `except C:`, and `except D:` handlers.

Thus, this code is equivalent to:

```
print "B"
print "C"
print "D"
```

Except that it will throw an (uncaught) exception if any of `B`, `C`, or `D` is not an exception.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of ridiculous. Its part of a basic python class, so its not really supposed to achieve anything apart from explaining the concept of exception handling in python.